# Choosing new number of levels for refactoring based on occurances

Tags: r, refactoring

My dataset has the following sample summary.

```
Location            No. of rows
 "AA"                   10000
 "BB"                   50000
 "CC"                   500
 "DD"                   5000
```

The number of location levels is around 150 in total and I would like to refactor it such that I have more or less similarly sized groups.

I am using `fct_lump(data$location,n=___)`

How can I find the optimal value of n (no. of levels) for this operation.

Comment: `fct_lump` groups all the least-frequent levels into one level, typically "Other." It gives various ways, including the `n = ` term, to set the cutoff between the levels it will lump together and the levels it will leave alone. It does not create groups from among the other levels, so it will not help in making "similarly sized groups."

Comment: It would help if you could provide an example of what output you would like to see. What does "more or less similarly sized groups" mean in your specific situation?

Comment: Given the example I shared, sample output that I am hoping for is 
Location                  "OtherAACCDD"          15500
 "BB"                              50000